# How to do conditional sum in formula fields on crystal report?

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am trying add a list of part amounts. I want to add only the amounts with ID as aa. I am using the below formuls:

```
shared numbervar aTotal;
if lcase({ID}) = 'aa' then
aTotal := aTotal + CDBL({Amount});
```

But it add up all datas. Help me on this

Comment: Where did you place that formula?

Comment: Inside a formula field

Comment: You can write only inside formula... i mean to ask you in which aection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
Create a formula `@Compute`

if lcase({ID}) = 'aa' then
CDBL({Amount});
else 0
```

Now in footer take sum of the formula `compute`